# still asking for password even after setting up the machine for Password-less SSH Login

Tags: ssh, centos, scp

I need to copy a file from a remote machine to my local machine and I need to automate it.

I've tried SCP command and it's working, however, I could not automate the part wherein it is asking for the password of the user of the local  machine and the remote machine.

Based on this [article](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/11/3-steps-to-perform-ssh-login-without-password-using-ssh-keygen-ssh-copy-id/) I can Perform SSH Login Without Password Using ssh-keygen & ssh-copy-id

after following all the instructions written there, I tried to access the remote machine using this

> ssh lalala@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX

it works, it doesnt ask for the password anymore. But when I tried copying a file from that machine using the command below,

```
scp lalala@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:'/a/b/c.txt' lelele@XXX.XXX.XXX.YYY:'/b/c/'
```

it still asks for the password of the localmachine which is the lelele@XXX.XXX.XXX.YYY

I wonder if I did something wrong? what could it be? is there something wrong with the format of the command?

BTW, im using Centos, and I'm planning to code it using python

Comment: This is weird. Are you sure the asked password is the one for lalala@ ? Could you paste your server sshd_config and authorized_keys files ?

Comment: yes. the complete output is this:                                             Enter passphrase for key 'home/USER/.ssh/id_rsa':                                lalala@localhost's password:

Comment: yes. the complete output is this:                                             Enter passphrase for key 'home/USER/.ssh/id_rsa':                                lalala@localhost's password:                                             scp: /b/c.txt : Permission Denied                              Killed by Signal 1.                                                 Connection to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX closed

Comment: @pistache some clarifications: when I was doing the key and it was asking for the passphrase, I didnt type any, which means it has no passphrase. I put the password for the remote machine after sending this command >>> ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub remote-host

Comment: Could you paste the full output on a site like http://pastebin.com/ (and then give me the link), of the command 'ssh -v lalala@localhost

Comment: Hi @pistache . hmmm.. which part of the output of ssh -v lalala@localhost do you need? , I want to clarify that the machine that is asking for password is the localhost

Answer (score 0):

If you are copying to your local machine why don't you just do

```
scp lalala@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:'/a/b/c.txt' /b/c/
```

?

I tried your line on some machine with similar setup and didn't get asked for password; I got an error instead, but this is probably due to differences in our configurations. I tried mine and it worked.

Regarding whether your connection succeeds in the remote machine you could tail this file there:

```
tail -f /var/log/secure
```

If you see no error there you can be sure (well, never say always) your layout with the generated keys is working.

In this case I bet you'll see no error there.

Edit 20240314

What I said in my original answer is still true. However, to get your command working you'd need to use ssh-copy-id to copy your key to your local machine too. That places your own key in you authorized keys file. If you're accessing your own machine by lelele@XXX.XXX.XXX.YYY, you also need to add your key there.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have multiple ssh keys and set identies only as yes. If so, please check this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/999306/398861